# Show/Hide Loading GIF Can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to show a loading GIF file while an ajax request is submitted. Below is my code, can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong? I want that as soon as the button is pressed it shows the loading GIF until the data comes back from the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-header">
<div class="loader" id="loader" style="display:none"></div> 
<div class="blog">
<input type="submit" value="Creat Jobs" id="createJobsButton"/>
<div id="resuls"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .loader{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:rgba(255,255,255, .8)url('../img/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat 50%
   }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#createJobsButton' ).click( function() {
                $('#loader').css('display', 'show');

                $.post( "services.php", {},
                    function( data ) 
                    {
                    $('#resuls').append(data);
                    $('#loader').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                );
            });
        }
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`$('#loader').css('display', 'show');`

to

`$('#loader').css('display', 'block');`

`display` does not have a show value.

Comment: Wow that was dumb on my end, thanks so much that fixed it!!! (its not letting me mark it as answered for another 4 minutes, I'm gonna mark it shortly). Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way of achieving this is by using `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`

Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins:

```
 $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
     $( "#loader" ).show();
 });
```

Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed:

```
 $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
     $( "#loader" ).hide();
 });
```